# Explanation of all uses of the escape character in Unix terminals

Tags: unix, terminal

I'd like to know all of the special uses of the escape character in Unix terminals, by which I mean the character `\e`. I know about colors and `\ec` which clears the screen in a scrollable terminal, what others are there and what do they do? For instance, what does this string do: `echo -e "\e[3;12r\e[3H"`?

Answer (score 1):

That particular example (both by the way are VT100 escapes where **`\e`** is used in some shells to mean the ASCII *escape* character):

- sets *scrolling margins* to lines 3 through 12 (starting from 1), and
- moves the cursor to the beginning of line 3 (putting it at the top of the scrolling margins)

By the way, **`\ec`** **resets** the terminal.  Clearing the screen is just one of several things done.

Further reading:

- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
- [vt100.net](http://vt100.net/)